# Excel cannot open Gembox Spreadsheet file

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, excel, gembox-spreadsheet

I have this code to generate an Excel file and download it:

```
SpreadsheetInfo.SetLicense("mycode"); 
ExcelFile myExcelFile = new ExcelFile();
ExcelWorksheet ws = myExcelFile.Worksheets.Add("Page 1");
myExcelFile.Save(Response, "asd.xlsx"); //this is for download
```

When I download the Excel file, it says:

> Either file type or file extension is not valid so Excel cannot open
>   this file. Confirm that file is not broken or file extension matches
>   file type.

I'm trying to solve this for hours but I couldn't find a solution. I use same code other places and it works, but it doesn't work  at this part of my project. Can you tell me what I should do? Thanks.

Comment: You should submit a support ticket to GemBox Software by using [this link](http://www.gemboxsoftware.com/support-center/new-ticket) and attach the corrupted file so that they can investigate the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to save the fire as an xls-file instead of an xlsx-file. I'm guessing that the default is xls. Excel can get confused if the file extension is wrong.

Comment: Well, that's progress :-) What now?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and it was caused by the worksheet title. The worksheet title should not be too long. I think the limit is 32 characters.

Answer (score 0):

HYE. TRY  THIS. 
I'VE TRY SOME EXAMPLES FROM GEMBOX SPREADSHEET WEBSITE.

```
Imports GemBox.Spreadsheet
Imports GemBox.Spreadsheet.WinFormsUtilities
Imports System.Data.OleDb
```

Public Class Form1

```
Public Sub New()
    SpreadsheetInfo.SetLicense("FREE-LIMITED-KEY")

    InitializeComponent()
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim openFileDialog = New OpenFileDialog()
    openFileDialog.Filter = "XLS files (*.xls, *.xlt)|*.xls;*.xlt|XLSX files (*.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xltx, *.xltm)|*.xlsx;*.xlsm;*.xltx;*.xltm|ODS files (*.ods, *.ots)|*.ods;*.ots|CSV files (*.csv, *.tsv)|*.csv;*.tsv|HTML files (*.html, *.htm)|*.html;*.htm"
    openFileDialog.FilterIndex = 2

    If (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK) Then
        Dim ef = ExcelFile.Load(openFileDialog.FileName)

        ' Export Excel worksheet to DataGridView control.
        DataGridViewConverter.ExportToDataGridView(ef.Worksheets.ActiveWorksheet, Me.DataGridView1, New ExportToDataGridViewOptions() With {.ColumnHeaders = True})
    End If



End Sub
```

THAT OPEN FILE DIALOG, YOU CAN MINIMIZE TO READ EXCEL FILE ONLY

Comment: YOU HAVE TO CLICK ADD REFERENCE AT YOUR PROJECT AND CHOOSE GEMBOX SPREADSHEET & GEMBOX WIN UTILITIES. MAKESURE IT HAS THE SAME VERSION OR ELSE IT WILL CORRUPT

Answer (score 0):

If you save the file to the folder and it works fine then check if your http response is modified before returned to the user.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpresponse.filter?view=netframework-4.8.1
If yes, add logic to exclude response modification by content type or other properties that suits your logic.